# how do i delete backspace key in my c++ program

Tags: visual-c++

```
__input create;__ 
//input is the class for saving username and password

char c = getch();
while(c!='\n'&&c!='\r'&&c!='\b') /*does my while loop have to be modified to 
check if the ASCII for backspace was entered*/  
{

    create.password += c;
    system("cls");

    cout << "Create an account" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Email: " << endl;

    cout << create.email << endl;


    cout << endl << "Username: " << endl;
    cout << create.name << endl;


    cout << endl << "Password: " << endl;
    cout << string(create.password.size(),'*');
```

//these are the inputs for username and password which as both strings

```
    c = getch();
}
```

//PS Im new to this so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Well, backspace is considered a `char` because it IS a `char`. Not a printable charachter though, but a controll character. If you have a look at an ASCII table, you will see that it is represented by the number `8` just like `'a' == 97`.

So, you can just check `c == 8` in your loop and do whatever you want, e.g. delete the last character of your password.

Comment: how would i delete the last character during the while loop?

Comment: That entirely depends on the datatype of `password`. You didn't tell that. If it is an `std::string` then `password.pop_pack()` will work.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It's `pop_back` not `pop_pack`

Comment: my password variable is a string. will i have to create a for loop where i<password.lenght(); and use a if statement to check if the ascii value for backspace was entered and use the pop_back function to delete it?.

Comment: No additional loop needed. In your current loop, check for backspace and delete a character. If it is not backspace, do what you are doing right now.